# Why does UndirectedGraph sometimes relabel vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Normally, `UndirectedGraph` preserves the vertex names and the vertex ordering.

```
UndirectedGraph[Graph[{"a" -> "b"}], VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But sometimes it does not:

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 0, 0 <-> 2}, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
dg = DirectedGraph[g, "Acyclic", VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ug = UndirectedGraph[%, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
EdgeList[g]
(* {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 0, 0 \[UndirectedEdge] 2} *)

EdgeList[ug]
(* {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3} *)
```

Is this inconsistency a bug?  What is different between the first directed graph and the above example and `dg` that causes `UndirectedGraph` to process them differently?

Comment: you should contact tech support for this.

Comment: @halmir Thanks for the comment.  I sent the report to support.

Comment: @halmir Thanks for fixing this one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with a graph with strings as vertex names leads to the same output:

```
g = Graph[{"b" <-> "a", "a" <-> "c"}, VertexLabels -> Automatic];
dg = DirectedGraph[g, "Acyclic", VertexLabels -> Automatic]
ug = UndirectedGraph[%, VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

[image]

It appeared to me that the vertex ordering is not changed but that vertices are merely replaced by their position within `VertexList[dg]`:

```
EdgeList[ug] == (UndirectedEdge @@@ EdgeList[dg] /. 
   AssociationThread[VertexList[dg], Range[VertexCount[dg]]])
```

> True

The problem seems to occur (only?) when the internal graph representation of the graph handed over to `UndirectedGraph` is by a `SparseArray` which is the case for `dg` but not for hand-woven graphs such as `g` or `UndirectedGraph[Graph[{"a" -> "b"}], VertexLabels -> Automatic]`

```
GraphComputation`GraphRepresentation[g]
GraphComputation`GraphRepresentation[ug]
```

> "Incidence"
>
> "Simple"

I observe a similar behavior also for graphs that have `Sparse` as result of `` GraphComputation`GraphRepresentation ``.

Another evidence is that we can use conversion of the internal graph representation as a workaround:

```
UndirectedGraph[
 GraphComputation`ToGraphRepresentation[dg, "Incidence"],
 VertexLabels -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image]

Summed up, I cannot imagine that this inconsistency were intentional. I vote for the bug tag.